# addveventlistener not working on media queries above 768px

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the site on firefox 49 and and chrome 63, same isssue, if i click on each holder [flip card], it works on iphone4, galaxy 5 and iphone 8, using chrome,however, after a few tries, if i switch orientation from 640px, to 320px, portrait view, the top flip card will not work immediately, instead i have to wait upto 30secs, and then it will work..above 768px none of the cards work....

```js
/**
 * Created by User1 on 16/01/2018.
 */

    //NAV
//dom query
    var btn3= document.getElementById('btn3');
    var btn= document.getElementById('btn');
    var nav=document.getElementById('nav_bar');



    //FLIP CARD

    //dom query

var card_holder=document.getElementsByClassName('card_holder');
var grid=document.getElementById('grid_container');






//array from card front

Array.from(card_holder).forEach(function(holder){

holder.addEventListener('click',function(e){

   holder.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('switch');
    holder.lastElementChild.classList.toggle('switchB');

console.log(holder)

});

  });


//nav event

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    //toggle menu
    nav.classList.toggle('viewer');
});





//btnbb3.addEventListener('click',function(){
    //alert('hiya');
  //grid.innerHTML+= '<p>hello</p>';
//});


//array from flip container

//Array.from(flipContainer).forEach(function(addContainer) {});
```

```css
/* ===============Mobile Layout ================*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}


img, embed, object, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ie6{
    width: 100%;
}



/* ============================================================
  BODY
============================================================ */

body{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#grid_container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* ============================================================
  HEADER
============================================================ */
header{
    background-color: #ff3599;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}


/* ============================================================
  NAVIGATION
============================================================ */

#nav_bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}


#nav_bar.viewer{
background-color: #1c2c74;
    opacity: 0.7;
}



#nav_bar a{
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

#nav_bar a:hover{
    color: #ff3599;
}


/* ============================================================
 ADVERT ANIMATION
============================================================ */


@keyframes im {

    0%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -100%;

    }

    25%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -75%;
    }

    50%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;
    }

    75%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -25%;
    }

    100%{

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
}







@keyframes im {

    0%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -100%;

    }

    25%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -75%;
    }

    50%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;
    }

    75%{
        position: absolute;
        left: -25%;
    }

    100%{

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
}






/* ============================================================
 ADVERT
============================================================ */

.advert{
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #77a7c7;
}


.advert img{
    height: inherit;
}

#img3{
    width: 100%;
     animation-name: im3;
    animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 30s;
}



#img1{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    animation-name: im1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 30s;
}



/* ============================================================
  FLIP
============================================================ */


.flip_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 10px;

}

.card_holder{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.card_front{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #ff3599;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


.card_back{
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #1c2c74;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}




.card_holder span{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50%;
    color: whitesmoke;
}


.card_front.switch{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card_back.switchB{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}





/* ============================================================
  INFO
============================================================ */


.info h2{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #77a7c7;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}

.info p{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #77a7c7;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* ============================================================
  FOOTER
============================================================ */


@media only screen and (min-width:360px){
    .card_holder{
        width: 340px;
    }

}




@media only screen and (min-width:480px){
.card_holder{
    width: 460px;
}
}



@media only screen and (min-width:640px){

    .flip_container{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .card_holder{
        width: 200px;
    }


}


@media only screen and (min-width:768px){


    .card_holder{
        width: 240px;
    }

}


@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    .card_holder{
        width: 324px;
    }
}



@media only screen and (min-width:1280px){
    .card_holder{
        width: 410px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1440px){
    .card_holder{
        width: 460px;

    }

    #grid_container{
        background-color: #000011;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flip.css"/>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<!--grid container-->
<div id="grid_container">


    <!--header-->
    <header>
<p id="btn">HHH</p>
        NSA..........

    </header>


    <!--navigation-->


    <nav id="nav_bar">

        <a>Home</a>
        <a>About us</a>
        <a>News</a>


    </nav>


    <!--advert container-->

    <div class="advert">

        <img id="img1" src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img id="img3" src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>

    </div>



    <!--flip container-->

    <div class="flip_container" id="flipCon">

        <div class="card_holder">
            <div class="card_front"><span>CARD 1 Front</span></div>
            <div class="card_back"><span>CARD 1 Back</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card_holder">
            <div class="card_front"><span>CARD 2 Front</span></div>
            <div class="card_back"><span>CARD 2 Back</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card_holder" >
            <div class="card_front"><span>CARD 3 Front</span></div>
            <div class="card_back"><span>CARD 3 Back</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="info">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>
            Aenean nec sollicitudin dolor. Praesent interdum accumsan odio, ut tristique lorem auctor sed. Vivamus dictum arcu venenatis ipsum pellentesque fringilla. Mauris rhoncus felis a rhoncus tristique. Etiam pretium convallis pretium. Donec feugiat ligula lorem, sed vestibulum leo rhoncus nec. Aliquam vehicula convallis leo ut ultricies. Cras vel justo sit amet risus cursus commodo in a nunc. Sed interdum consectetur nisl id ultricies. Nullam sit amet mi in massa facilisis maximus.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="info">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>
            Aenean nec sollicitudin dolor. Praesent interdum accumsan odio, ut tristique lorem auctor sed. Vivamus dictum arcu venenatis ipsum pellentesque fringilla. Mauris rhoncus felis a rhoncus tristique. Etiam pretium convallis pretium. Donec feugiat ligula lorem, sed vestibulum leo rhoncus nec. Aliquam vehicula convallis leo ut ultricies. Cras vel justo sit amet risus cursus commodo in a nunc. Sed interdum consectetur nisl id ultricies. Nullam sit amet mi in massa facilisis maximus.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>
            Aenean nec sollicitudin dolor. Praesent interdum accumsan odio, ut tristique lorem auctor sed. Vivamus dictum arcu venenatis ipsum pellentesque fringilla. Mauris rhoncus felis a rhoncus tristique. Etiam pretium convallis pretium. Donec feugiat ligula lorem, sed vestibulum leo rhoncus nec. Aliquam vehicula convallis leo ut ultricies. Cras vel justo sit amet risus cursus commodo in a nunc. Sed interdum consectetur nisl id ultricies. Nullam sit amet mi in massa facilisis maximus.
        </p>
    </div>


    <!--footer-->

    <footer></footer>

</div>

</body>

<script src="js/flip.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Since your animation takes 30 seconds and you have alot of absolutely positioned elements, I have a hunch that something overlaps the clickable area during the transition.

Comment: many,many thanx...the problem was from the navigation bar [#nav_bar]being postioned absolute and the height being set to 100%, with a z-index of 3, [the z-index, shouldn't theoretically affect the area ,where the flip card is situated] on the nav_bar, by setting the height to anything below 70%, the flip card works fine now on all media queries, the animation caused no issues in this case, i tested it, thanx again

Answer (score 0):

.the problem was from the navigation bar [#nav_bar]being postioned absolute and the height being set to 100%, with a z-index of 3,when toggled and opacity is 1, i can see it covers the flip card surface area, i have changed the height of the nav_bar to 50%, at 70% it would still cover the top half of the flip card.
 Everything now works fine, the animation caused no issue, many thanx Shilly, for the direction where to look to address the problem...